# Most efficient way to populate array from database values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, populate

If I wanted to get a list of product_ids with a certain brand. I would do this:

```
$id_list = array();
$qry = 'SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_brand = :brand';
$STH = $this->pdo->prepare($qry);
$STH->execute(array("brand" => $brand));
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $STH->fetch())
{
    $id_list[] = $row['product_id'];
}
```

Is there a faster more efficient way? It seems like if I am only selecting 1 column there should be a better approach to selecting/inserting that into an array.

Comment: Do you have any reason to ask such a question?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, yes. I have different tables for different types of products. So to generate a list of all product_ids with a certain condition I need to run something like the above on each table. (they all are tied to a base table so the ID's don't overlap). So am searching each product type table for products that meet the condition, and storing the results in an array. Then once I have an array of all the matching product ids. I will loop through them and pass them into my product class that will list them on the page.

Comment: .. So since I am going to be making the above call multiple times (on different tables) I wanted to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: That is what you are doing wrong. A **real** optimization would be to avoid such multiple selects and let database do this job.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, your right. I am merely testing/prototyping different ideas trying to come up with the most efficient way to meet my requirements. Which require complex filtering. I was previously selecting matching products and putting them in a temp table before applying more filtering. Now I was trying to create an array of ids and use IN() + more filters. Which like you said, isn't ideal either. But I am not a mysql expert and I am learning by doing. But if nothing else I still learned something useful from wrikken, whether I use this design or not.

Comment: Well being not a mysql expert you are asking not mysql assistance but just for API function that can be easily found in the manual. A useless one. Good way of learning. Go on.

Comment: Ah. the folly of the aged, barking a the youngins for not trying to find things out, and barking at the youngins when they try to find out the 'wrong' thing, making acquiring knowledge a happy lottery of abuse, with the occasional winning ticket called _'grumpily mumbling you already knew that 20 years ago, and it should be basic knowledge for anyone'_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
$id_list = $STH->fetchAll();
```

Is it really faster? Local benchmarK:

```
$ cat 1.php 
<?php
$d = new PDO('mysql:localhost');
$qry = 'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE bar FROM test.foo'; //for completeness sake: foo has 400 rows
$stmt = $d->query($qry);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
$check = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
$ cat 2.php 
<?php
$d = new PDO('mysql:localhost');
$qry = 'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE bar FROM test.foo'; //for completeness sake: foo has 400 rows
$stmt = $d->query($qry);
$check = array();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $check[] = $row['bar'];
}
?>
$ time (for i in {1..100}; do php 1.php; done;)

real    0m4.507s
user    0m2.392s
sys     0m1.288s
$ time (for i in {1..100}; do php 2.php; done;)

real    0m6.830s
user    0m3.352s
sys     0m2.328s
```

.. so, at least this script difference, on my server, is faster...

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks!.. I knew there had to be something... Question tho, is this actually faster or just require less typing?

Comment: Hmm, less arrays created, I'd think it's negligible, but I'll have a benchmark in a few minutes.

Comment: oh no. Wrikken and his trained zillion iterations tests again.

Comment: Zillion? As if my computer didn't have anything better to do. And AFAIK this is only my second I posted on SO. Feel free to suffer horrible despair because the actual benchmarking, or gloat mercilessly because someone has yet again taken the bait, dear Shrappy.

Comment: No M. Collateral Damage, the question was 'is this faster', to which the answer is (under certain conditions) 'yes'. The question was not _'Will it make my application much faster?'_, to which you, I and probably the OP know the answer: not really enough to care. The question certainly was not _'Do I even select the proper records'_ or _'What's the biggest speedgain I can get in my application'_. Also in real life, there are other sites & applications then your average home demolishment blog or news about the tramp next door in which selecting hundreds of rows is a valid practice. _/hungry_

Comment: Don't bother to explain. I know it already. The only thing you're interested in, is reputation points. Don't worry, you'll get enough.

Comment: Dear Rusty Landmine, your arguments don't hold up, your research skills are sorely lacking, and overall the only thing I'm really interested in while visiting this site is of course dodging the possibility of doing some actual real work, just like the rest. Your limited worldview and experience is elas no fault of mine,  and your bitterness about actual in the field practices has jaded your appreciation for nuggets of knowledge that don't necessarily encompass a full project. I don't blame you for it, I'll see you there in about 3 short years I believe.